XPath identification in Magnolia or for div class
Iam very new to Automation and have difficulty in identifying Xpath.
Here if i have to identify xpath for a divclass-child at a specific level in the hierarchy, for e.g 5th div child.Is there anyway to identify it?Do you recommend any tool for that?Thanks
I tried copying the direct xpath

//*[@id="authormagnoliaadmincentral-458764548"]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]
Also tried with //div[@class='icon']//div[@class='label' and text()='Seit']")-by giving only one parent.

For all that getting the error -no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='icon']//div[@class='label' and text()='Seiten']"} (Session info: chrome=128.0.6613.137)

Please, take some time to read how to ask and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Add the html page source and mention which element you are trying to access.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In your error message the XPath expression says text()='Seit', but in your example your XPath expression says text()='Seiten'. NB these two predicates could both be true only if your div contained two next nodes, for example: <div class='label'>Seit<br/>Seiten</div>, which seems unlikely. You must provide the actual HTML before anyone will be able to help you.
